# Is there a built in variable from java's libraries for the full alphabet?

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I want to test if a word dies not contain **any letter of the alphabet** (a-z, A-Z) but searching for a better method than

```
if (!(str.contains("a") || str.contains("b") || ...)) { 
    ...
}
```

or creating a `String` array with all possible letters and checking against that.

Note that `!str.isEmpty()` will not work because spaces must also be accounted for or other characters

**Is there some variable with he entire alphabet or a built in method to check for a string with no letters?**

Comment: Research "regular expressions".

Comment: [Search](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20java%20match%20letters%20a-z&tts=st_asaf_macos) Stack Overflow before posting.

Comment: Maybe `(!str.matches(".*\\p{Alpha}.*"))`

Comment: Have you considered accented characters such as `é ñ ö` ?  Not common in English but some people _may_ use them depending on what the field is for.

Comment: Even shorter:  `s.matches("\\P{L}*")`

Comment: "**Is there some variable with he entire alphabet or a built in method to check for a string with no letters?**" - **No**.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/208/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways

1.

```
if (!str.matches(".*[a-zA-Z].*"))
```

This is a regular expression. It will check that the string contains any character between `a` and `z` or between `A` and `Z`.

2.

```
if (str.chars().noneMatch(Character::isLetter)
```

This is probably more efficient than the regex and will check that no character is a letter.

Comment: Worth noting that your two versions are subtly different. First version only checks for A-Z (IOW English alphabets only), whereas the second version accounts for accented characters.